# Getting sys.argv[] values from flask form data showing error

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I've two python files. One is nnet_comb_mod.py and another one is nnet_flask.py which creates a form to get the arguments for running the nnet_comb_mod.py file. nnet_comb_mod.py is run as

```
python3 nnet_comb_mod.py some_file.csv 15 21 1000 5000 0.8 1.2
```

where all the numbers and floats are accessed as sys.argv[x]. The nnet_flask.py code is :

```
import nnet_comb_mod
# import other modules
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def upload_file():
    return '''<html><h1>Upload a file</h1>
    <body><form action = "http://127.0.0.1:8085/fup" method = "POST" enctype ="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file"/>
    <input type="number" name="low_hl"/>
    ...
    <input type="submit"/></form></body></html> '''

@app.route('/fup',methods=['GET','POST'])
def upload_link():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['file']
        g = request.form.get('low_hl')
        ...
        app.config['upfls'] = "./"
        f.save(os.path.join(app.config['upfls'], f.filename))
        f.close()
        cmd2 = "python nnet_comb_mod.py ./"+f.filename+" "+g+" "+h+" "+i+" "+j+" "+k+" "+l
        cmd2 = str(cmd2)
        g = proc2.Group()
        p2 = g.run(cmd2)
        def read():
            while g.is_pending():
                lines = g.readlines()
                for proc,line in lines:
                    yield str(line) + "\n"
        return Response(read() , mimetype = 'text/event-stream')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8085,debug=True)
```

It throws error :

```
File "H:\nnet_comb_mod.py", line 35, in <module>
hidlay_btm = sys.argv[2]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How to get the flask form datas as the arguments of the nnet_comb_mod.py ?

Comment: You need to show the code of that module. But why are you doing it like this? Can't you rewrite that as a function which accepts the data as arguments?

Comment: You import `nnet_comb_mod` but then later you call it as `"python nnet_comb_mod.py"` not using the import. So you could just remove the import, or better modify the imported module adding `if __name__ == '__main__'` etc.